# Exit a method if another thread is executing it

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have a method in a multi-threaded application and I'd like the following behavior when this method is invoked:

1. If no other threads are currently executing the method, execute it.
2. If another thread is currently executing the method then exit the method without executing it.

The `lock` statement in C# is useful for waiting until a thread has completed execution, but I don't want to serialize access to this method but rather bypass executing said method if it is being executed by another thread.

Comment: Favorited this one. Before, I was trying to solve this problem by making a thread that loops over the method and uses a "hail mary" combo of `volatile bool`, `lock`, and `AutoResetEvent`. (throws up in mouth...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose I don't understand... if it should only be called by one thread at a time, why are multiple threads calling it to begin with?

Anyway, you can use [Monitor.TryEnter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx).  It doesn't block and returns `false` if it fails to acquire a lock. In that case you can just return from the function.

Comment: it can be called by any thread at any time, but if it is called by Thread A and Thread B is in the middle of executing it then Thread A should exit the method call rather than executing it once Thread B finishes.

Comment: @ScottMitchell +1. In my case, the method's business logic is such that if Thread B calls while A is executing, I know that the operation from Thread A's method call will satisfy the result for Thread B. For example, my method basically calls a stored procedure in a database which updates a bunch of records. (I don't want to run that stored procedure over and over again when it gets called from multiple threads since the I/O is expensive)

Answer (score 13):

You can do this using Monitor.TryEnter, but perhaps more simply: Interlocked:

```
int executing; // make this static if you want this one-caller-only to
               // all objects instead of a single object
void Foo() {
    bool won = false;
    try {
        won = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref executing, 1, 0) == 0;
        if(won) {
           // your code here
        }
    } finally {
        if(won) Interlocked.Exchange(ref executing, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson for lock-free coding, `Interlocked` is the main go-to weapon. In fact, it is what the compiler uses to do the thread-safety in field-like-events.

Comment: +1 for `Interlocked`. For some reason, `Monitor.TryEnter` is very slow when returning `false`.

Comment: +1 from me as well.  If `Monitor.TryEnter()` proves to be an issue, this is the correct approach (not to say that `Monitor.TryEnter()` is *more* correct).

Answer (score 0):

create bool variable somewhere else, set on true when start method and to false on exit from method, before run method check if variable is false then run else exit from method

Comment: The variable would need to be static if it were to be shared by different threads.

Comment: @Oded Unless all of the threads had access to the same instance, or the threads only need to be prevented from concurrently running the method on the same instance.

Comment: @Servy - Fair enough, though I don't see mention of the holding class being a singleton or a static class.

Comment: @Oded It wouldn't need to be either; just an instance that is shared between threads.  It's easy enough to happen; closures are one common way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helper method for this purpose:

```
static class Throttle
{
    public static void RunExclusive(ref int isRunning, Action action)
    {
        if (isRunning > 0) return;

        bool locked = false;
        try
        {
            try { }
            finally
            {
                locked = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isRunning, 1, 0) == 0;
            }

            if (locked) action();
        }
        finally 
        { 
            if (locked) 
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref isRunning, 0); 
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
private int _isTuning = 0;
private void Tune() { ... }

...

Throttle.RunExclusive(ref _isTuning, Tune);
```