# Skipping a method when it is already executed by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

My question is related to this one: [Exit a method if another thread is executing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412204/exit-a-method-if-another-thread-is-executing-it)

There is a method which is is executed by multiple threads. If one thread is executing the method any other thread should just exit. My solution is like this:

```
public class ReentrantLockTest implements Runnable {

    private static final ReentrantLock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (LOCK.tryLock()) {
            System.out.println("Aquired. Thread "  + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try {
                // do stuff here

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle errors
            } finally {
                // release the lock
                LOCK.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

This seems fine to me but in production it sometimes happens that the lock remains unreleased thus the method is not getting executed at all unless I restart the system.

So I have two questions:
1. How is it possible that the lock doesn't get released?
2. What is a good way of testing such code? Just running this in a loop and hope it'll crash at some point if there's a bug doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: We would need to see what you are doing in the '// do stuff here' section, it may be that this never terminates for some thread.

Comment: @mwarren that's a very good point. I should have thought of that. I'm reading from a HttpUrlConnection and after adding some debug output and lots of waiting the problem occured again and it turned out that it gets stuck during read(). I had set the connectTimeout but not the readTimeout. I assume that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: Absolutely, if the read() blocks then the lock will not be released.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *synchronised* keyword. This ensures that only one thread executes a block of code at the same time.

Change your method to:

```
public synchronised void run() {
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package thread;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ReentrantLockTest implements Runnable 
{
    private static final ReentrantLock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        boolean done = false; 
        while (!done) 
        {
            boolean ans=LOCK.tryLock();
        if(ans) 
            {
            System.out.println("Aquired. Thread "  + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try {
                // do stuff here
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " in try block");
                done = true;    
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // handle errors
            } finally {
                // release the lock
                LOCK.unlock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" unlock");
                }
            }
        else
            { 
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()  + " waiting for lock"); 
            try
            {Thread.sleep(1000);} 
            catch(InterruptedException e) 
                {e.printStackTrace();} 
            }
      }
   }
}


public class ReentrantLockDemo2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ExecutorService pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Runnable t1=new ReentrantLockTest();
        Runnable t2=new ReentrantLockTest();
        Runnable t3=new ReentrantLockTest();
        Runnable t4=new ReentrantLockTest();

        pool.execute(t1);
        pool.execute(t2);
        pool.execute(t3);
        pool.execute(t4);

        pool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Main Close");
    }
}
```